# Python list index out of range but shouldn't be

Tags: python, while-loop, indexoutofrangeexception

startDate, stopDate, startTime, stopTime, startBehavior, and stopBehavior are all lists with the same length. I'm getting a list index out of range in line 5 (if startDate[i] != stopDate[j]) and I'm not sure why. It was working before and now it's not. I'm trying to print the specific behaviors based on the conditions in the if/elif statements.

```
i = 0
while (i < len(startDate)):
    j = 0
    while (j < len(stopDate)):
        if startDate[i] != stopDate[j]:
            j += 1
        elif startDate[i] == stopDate[j]:
            if stopTime[j] < startTime[i]:
                j += 1
            elif stopTime[j] > startTime[i]:
                if startBehavior[i] != stopBehavior[j]:
                    j += 1
                elif startBehavior[i] == stopBehavior[j]:
                    print(startBehavior[i])
                    print(stopBehavior[j])
                    print('')
                    i += 1
```

any help would be appreciated! thank you in advanced!

Comment: Please give the full code

Comment: Have you checked the values of `i` and `j`?

Comment: To be able to answer, we need the values of startDate etc, also i and j at the time of the exception.

Have you run the code through PyLint ?

Comment: As an aside, the code should be simplified - good code should not be hard to understand, but does require a few revisions from "first cut". For example, the code to line 6 is is just advancing until startDate[i] == stopDate[j] - so why not do that as step 1, and de-nest somewhat. Similarly for the other conditions.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the following snippet, it will run forever, even though i is clearly greater than 100.

```
i = 0
while i < 100:
    while True:
        i += 1
        print(i)
```

Your code is doing something similar -- in the case that `i == len(startDate) - 1`; `startDate[i] == stopDate[j]`; `stopTime[j] > startTime[i]`; and `startBehavior[i] == stopBehavior[j]`, your code will increment i so that `i == len(startDate)`, and then, since `j < len(stopDate)` is still `True`, you will not have exited your *second* while loop. When you try to access `startDate[i]`, you will get an `IndexError`.

This is somewhat data-dependent so it is possible that it worked before without ever having this issue.

Comment: Ok this makes sense, do you have any ideas of that to fix with j < len(stopDate) to exit that loop?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you need to do, but one while loop with `while i < len(startDate) and j < len(stopDate)` might be useful.